# Realm crash when invalidating while updating

Tags: objective-c, crash, realm

I have a constant crash on Realm when I try to remove the database while I'm still running update events in other thread.

The crash is:

```
2017-08-14 18:07:56.289 App Staging[28264:7828070] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c67fb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c0e4141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Realm                               0x0000000108095f96 _ZL27RLMVerifyInWriteTransactionP8RLMRealm + 86
    3   Realm                               0x000000010809710a RLMCreateObjectInRealmWithValue + 138
    4   Realm                               0x00000001080820af +[RLMObject createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:] + 607
    5   App Staging                         0x0000000107497ae0 +[RealmRoundable createOrUpdateInRealm:withMemberResponse:] + 400
    6   App Staging                         0x0000000107497916 +[RealmRoundable createOrUpdateWithMemberResponse:] + 118
    7   App Staging                         0x000000010742a0a0 +[RealmStaff createOrUpdateInRealm:withResponse:inCareProvider:] + 352
    8   App Staging                         0x000000010742ab92 +[RealmStaff createOrUpdateInRealm:withStaff:inCareProvider:] + 514
    9   App Staging                         0x000000010742a94b +[RealmStaff createOrUpdateStaff:inCareProvider:] + 139
    10  App Staging                         0x000000010733b803 -[StaffRoundableTableViewController updateRoundables:fromDataLoader:inCareProvider:] + 131
    11  App Staging                         0x000000010747ae3a __54-[RoundableTableViewController dataLoaderDidLoadData:]_block_invoke.324 + 122
    12  Realm                               0x00000001081d01a6 -[RLMRealm transactionWithBlock:error:] + 86
    13  Realm                               0x00000001081d010e -[RLMRealm transactionWithBlock:] + 62
    14  App Staging                         0x000000010747ab0d __54-[RoundableTableViewController dataLoaderDidLoadData:]_block_invoke + 765
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e15c4a6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e18505c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e164dcd _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1321
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e166ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e166bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e51c5a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e51c07d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This happens when I call:

```
[RealmManager deleteRealm];
```

Which is implemented as:

```
+ (void)deleteRealm
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] invalidate];
        // Hack to force Realm to clear cache because config is cached and crashes eventually because it detects encryption key has changed
        SUPPRESS_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR_WARNING([[RLMRealm class] performSelector:@selector(resetRealmState)]);
    }

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    NSArray<NSURL *> *realmFileURLs = @[
                                        config.fileURL,
                                        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"lock"],
                                        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"log_a"],
                                        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"log_b"],
                                        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"note"],
                                        [[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.realm.management", [[config.fileURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] lastPathComponent]]]
                                        ];
    for (NSURL *URL in realmFileURLs) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [manager removeItemAtURL:URL error:&error];
        if (error) {
            // handle error
            DDLogError(@"Error deleting realm file - %@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: is there a way to **stop all Realm operations** before running this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Realm's documentation on [Deleting Realm Files](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#deleting-realm-files):

> Because Realm avoids copying data into memory except when absolutely required, all objects managed by a Realm contain references to the file on disk, and must be deallocated before the file can be safely deleted. This includes all objects read from (or added to) the Realm, all `RLMArray`, `RLMResults`, and `RLMThreadSafeReference` objects, and the `RLMRealm` itself.
>
> In practice, this means that deleting a Realm file should be done either on application startup before you have opened the Realm, or after only opening the Realm within an explicit autorelease pool, which ensures that all of the Realm objects will have been deallocated.

Removing the file while it's still being accessed them on another thread will lead to all sorts of problems. Calling into Realm's private methods, such as `+[RLMRealm resetRealmState]`, will too. I'd strongly suggest doing neither of these things.

You might approach this in slightly different ways, depending on what the motivation is for removing the Realm file from disk. If you can share more information about your use case I might be able to provide a more specific suggestion.

For instance, you could keep track of whether your background threads are actively working with the Realm and only delete it once they're idle. You need to be very careful to ensure that all references to the Realm have been dropped at the point you remove the file, though, otherwise you could end up continuing to access the now-deleted file via an already-open file handle.

Alternatively, instead of immediately deleting the Realm file you could instead generate a new, unique path for the new Realm file. You would then delete the Realm files that are not being used when you're sure that the remainder of your app is not using them (next launch is a very reliable way of achieving this, or otherwise tying it to points in your app lifecycle where you know the old state can no longer be accessed). This would be my preference as there's no chance of removing the file while it's being used. It's also a good fit for many apps that have the concept of logging a user out, as a different Realm path per user is a relatively easy concept to grasp.

Comment: We remove the Realm for HIPAA compliance reasons when the user ends a session. We used to do this with Encrypted Core Data but now we are doing this huge migration to Realm and to pass the audit we have to remove all traces of the database.

Comment: Would using an encrypted Realm, discarding the encryption key when the session ends, and then cleaning up the file at a later time satisfy the requirements?

Comment: I'll try to sell it. Right now I could avoid crashing by running this before removing the Realm file.

Comment: [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] beginWriteTransaction];
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] deleteAllObjects];
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] commitWriteTransaction];